# How to trigger select option on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selector

I want some JavaScript which can trigger/open select option while someone click on button using below code for select option

```
<div class="period" title="Choose a number of nights">
<span class="label">Nights</span>
<span class="input">
<select rel="period" value="4">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select></span></div>
```

Using below code for button

```
<td class="total">
<a class="im-pricebutton has-hover" href="javascript://;" value="A 2 night booking condition applies to this period">
<span class="book im-pricebutton-label">Min 2 nights</span>
<span class="number im-pricebutton-amount">$0</span>
</a></td>
```

As of now I have setup condition of Minimum night select as a 3,5 and 10 it's very on products so when someone don't pass this night function it'll show above code to select minimum night but how to pass some custom JavaScript which can open up drop down automatically when they click on button.

Comment: use `label` for that,

Comment: Did you really need 31 options in your sample html?

Comment: @nnnnnn : updated :p

Comment: To be clear, the select code will reside inside the <td class="total"> also?

Comment: Then, if they click on the offer inside the <td>'s link, you want to replace the offer or include the select option below it?

Comment: @nocturns2 : select code is outside of <td class="total"> If they click on button then I just want to open selector so user can get to know it's indicate to changing night option and they can select some option from dropdown list.

Comment: You might want to change the value= attribute in your link to or add a title=attribute if you want to show that info on link hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the way how to switch the value using below code. So, when someone click on button it'll take minimum night value, in this case it's 2. So, it's supplying value dynamically.

```
$('.period select').val(2).trigger('change');
```

Thanks for your suggestion and help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put ID on your select. `select id="selectbox"` and add this script.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X2rAZ/4/

```js
var button = document.querySelector('.im-pricebutton'),
    sel = document.getElementById('selectbox');

button.onclick = function(){
    open(sel);
}

function open(elem) {
    if (document.createEvent) {
        var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        elem[0].dispatchEvent(e);
    } else if (element.fireEvent) {
        elem[0].fireEvent("onmousedown");
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="period" title="Choose a number of nights">
<span class="label">Nights</span>
<span class="input">
<select rel="period" select id="selectbox">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select></span></div>
<br/><br/>
<br/><br/>
<br/><br/>
<td class="total">
<a class="im-pricebutton has-hover" href="javascript://;" value="A 2 night booking condition applies to this period">
<span class="book im-pricebutton-label">Min 2 nights</span>
<span class="number im-pricebutton-amount">$0</span>
</a></td>
```

- credits to EG.arteezy for open function.

Comment: This doesn't work. Calling `.click()` on a select element doesn't make its options list drop down.

Comment: @user111111 : is it not possible to do without adding any ID or class? specially looking on the current code.

I have tried to do using $('.period select').attr('size','10'); but after selecting value it's not hiding automatically

Comment: @nnnnnn: right it's not working using .click() here is the sample http://jsfiddle.net/X2rAZ/3/

Comment: Updated my answer. Try to look at it. I hope I answered it correctly now.

Comment: @user111111 Thanks for the update but It's still not working for me I have run code snippet

Comment: @GroupOfOceninfo what browser are you using?

Comment: @user6879896 I'm using Chrome Version 94.0.4606.61 (Official Build) (64-bit) and doesn't work for me in the code snippet,

Comment: I presume that the js is excuted before the dom is ready.

Comment: Doesn't even work in Chrome Version 96

Answer (score -1):

Would something like this work for you?
I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, so I made up my own sample.
I've added a snippet below.

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.total').click(function () {
                $('.period').css("display", "inline-block").slideDown();
            })
        });
```

```css
        td{
            padding: 10px;
        }
        .period {
            display: none;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>

        <td class="total">
            <a class="im-pricebutton has-hover" href="javascript://;" value="A 2 night booking condition applies to this period">
                <span class="book im-pricebutton-label">Min 2 nights</span>
                <span class="number im-pricebutton-amount">$0</span>
            </a>
        </td>

        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="period" title="Choose a number of nights">
    <span class="label">Nights</span>
    <span class="input">
        <select rel="period" value="4">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
    </span>
</div>
```